# Insert "-" between numbers while typing on edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am trying to format the value on edit text, as the user types. What i want is that the user should be be able to type, and see changes as the input is given.

My requirement is that after, 3 digits types, a hyphen should be appended, after the first hyphen, another 4 digits will be typed, then another hyphen is to be appended, then after seven digits and then after 1. So basically, the formatting should look like this: 123-1234-1234567-1.

Now, the problem is such that i am able to achieve this with standard text watcher, but while using backspace key, or delete on soft input keyboard, this malfunctions.

My code is below:

```
mEditText = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
```

My Text watcher:

```
private TextWatcher mTextWatcher= new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        } 
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            String str = charSequence.toString();  
            mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

                    if(keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && mEditText.getText().toString().length() != 0){
                        if(mEditText.getText().length()==4 ||mEditText.getText().length()==9 ||mEditText.getText().length()==17 ||mEditText.getText().length()==19)
                        {
                            String tempString;
                            char[] stringArray;
                            tempString=mEditText.getText().toString()+"-";
                            char c=tempString.charAt(tempString.length()-2);

                            if(c!='-')
                            {
                                stringArray = tempString.toCharArray();
                                stringArray[tempString.length()-2]=stringArray[tempString.length()-1];
                                stringArray[tempString.length()-1]=c;                                     
                                tempString=new String(stringArray);
                                mEditText.setText(tempString);
                                mEditText.setSelection(tempString.length());
                                tempString=null;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });        
        }   
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if (editable.length() == 3) {
                editable.append('-');
            }
        }
    };
```

Then, my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/myEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="18"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I want the operations to be performed in onTextChanged, as this method is called when the user is typing. My formatting is working fine, but if the user points the cursor to any digit in between and deletes a number, the formatting breaks, and another hyphen is appended at the end. So basically, i want to elegantly handle delete key on soft keyboard(i know no events are given for this), and then if the user types another number, it should be placed at the cursor location, and not at the end.

Comment: What do you mean by **malfunctions**?

Comment: by malfunctions, i mean, the number before the cursor is deleted (as expected), but then as soon as we type another number, the formatting breaks, a hyphen is appended at the end, and the number is not taken as the input.Also, the cursor then points towards the end.

Comment: you should put that as a part of the question, preferably with an example

Comment: I've asked the same, as part of the question. But, thanks for the suggestion, i will change it.

Comment: try [maskEditText library](https://github.com/VicMikhailau/MaskedEditText)

Comment: Tried this also, does not work, when user presses delete on this, from the soft keyboard, it behaves the same way as my code works. Also, input type is a problem here, i need only numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that with [PatternedTextWatcher](https://github.com/zsavely/PatternedTextWatcher).

Simple one line solution

1) Add this to your `gradle` file compile `'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'`

2) Then your `EditText` will look like this

```
mEditText = findViewById(R.id.mEditText);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new PatternedTextWatcher("###-####-#######-#"));
```

**Final Result**

Works like a charm without any flaw
[image]

Comment: Can you show me the xml for this? The input type i guess is not specified, as i am able to see the full keyboard, i want only numbers. I tried the same, using this lib, but not working. Can you put the same xml as i used, and try giving the input type as numbers?

Comment: Also, even with the input type not specified, try deleting 2 characters from somewhere in between, after which try adding the 2 characters, it will append the hyphen at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android (they have migrated to Kotlin, but there is should Java version too).

Answer (score 0):

I would put the code in afterTextChanged. I would then just look at the whole string, remove any non-number parts and insert hyphens as necessary at the right intervals. I think this would handle things well.

So you need a method to turn something like "25274*8f3h983t3" into "252-7483-9833". The effect of this would be that non-number characters the user types would be removed straight away and they could add digits anywhere in the string with the hyphens automatically repositioning.

Eg) The person types "12345678"

After the first 3, nothing would happen. Once they typed a 4, your code would add a hyphen behind it (123-4). Once they typed the 8, another hyphen would be added (123-4567-8). If they backspace the 8, the hyphen would also be removed. I think this'll work quite well.